# Hash equality in Crystal specs

Tags: specifications, crystal-lang

I'm getting:

```rb
       Expected: {text: "Hello World"}
            got: {:text => "Hello World"}
```

When the key is a symbol.

And

```rb
       Expected: {text: "Hello World"}
            got: {"text" => "Hello World"}
```

When the key is a string.

How can I output `{text: "Hello World"}`?

My code:

```rb
@output = {} of Symbol => Output'
@output[name] = @buffer # name is a Symbol

language.parse("Hello World").should eq({ text: "Hello World" })
```

And to use a string I do:

```rb
@output = {} of String => Output'
@output[name.to_s] = @buffer # name is a Symbol
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, `{text: "Hello World"}` is a [NamedTuple](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/1.4/syntax_and_semantics/literals/named_tuple.html), so you're comparing a `Hash` to a `NamedTuple`. What you need is `{:text => "Hello World"}` or `{"text" => "Hello World"}`. See the docs of [Hash](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/1.4/syntax_and_semantics/literals/hash.html) for details.